How to track and evaluate LLM Models from Amazon Bedrock (e.g., Claude) with MLflow?
I know I can use MLflow to track LLM models and evaluate their performance.
For OpenAI models, I can use the following code snippet to log the model and evaluate it:
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    system_prompt = "Answer the following question in two sentences“

    basic_qa_model = mlflow.openai.log_model(
        model="gpt-4o-mini",
        task=openai.chat.completions,
        artifact_path="model",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": system_prompt},
            {"role": "user", "content": "{question}"},
        ],
    )
    results = mlflow.evaluate(
        basic_qa_model.model_uri,
        eval_df,
        targets="ground_truth",  # specify which column corresponds to the expected output
        model_type="question-answering",  # model type indicates which metrics are relevant for this task
        evaluators="default",
    )
results.metrics

However, I now want to track a model like Claude 3.5-sonnet running on Amazon Bedrock using MLflow, but I couldn’t find a direct integration or documentation for this scenario.
Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to log and evaluate LLM models from Bedrock with MLflow, similar to how it’s done with OpenAI models?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Check this issue some code shows integration with Bedrock with Claude model : https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/11315   specific conf by provider and endpoints are here https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/llms/deployments/index.html#supported-provider-models:~:text=Supported%20Provider%20Models
